# non-recursive shutil.copytree in python

Tags: python, shutil, copytree

I am pretty new to using python and am trying to create a new folder structure for some files.  I am using os, shutil, and copytree to do the following:

ORIGINAL FOLDER STRUCTURE:

top_folder/

```
    batch1/
        1.tif
        1.xml
        2.tif
        2.xml
        hello.tif
        hello.xml

    batch2/
        purple.tif
        purple.xml
        red.tif
        red.xml
```

RESULTING FOLDER STRUCTURE:

top_folder/

```
    batch1/
        1/
            1.tif
            1.xml
        2/
            2.tif
            2.xml
        hello/
            hello.tif
            hello.xml

    batch2/
        purple/
            purple.tif
            purple.xml
        red/
            red.tif
            red.xml
```

My question is: how do I use copytree and get it to copy only the first two levels of folders, but then copytree stops and then I have my own code to transform the rest of the folder structure within the batch folders?

Here is my code:

```
import os, shutil, errno
def copy(src, dest):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dest)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
            #code here to transform folders
                else:
                    break
            else:
                print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `ignore` argument of `copytree` to help with this. Basically you could use it to setup a `glob` pattern which includes everything but the directories/files you do want to copy, and then it should match all the others, and thus ignore them. You can create a customized `ignore` function to behave as you'd like.

See more details here, including example code: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#copytree-example

Comment: Can you use a glob pattern to ignore an entire level of directories?  e.g. copy*/copy2*/ignore_all_folders

Comment: The `ignore` function is supposed to take the `src` path and a list of files (`names`), so you should be able to use that to essentially whitelist just the relative paths of the directories you're interested in.